# How to set up a local config for MariaDB on Mac

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have installed MariaDB server on my Mac using homebrew. I can access it no problem but I need to set up a local config file using the `mysql_config_editor` command. When I try to do that I get a `zsh: command not found: mysql_config_editor` error.

After some googling I found that I need to export the path to mysql folder in the zshrc file. I had trouble finding the actual folder I need to reference as it does not seem to be in the same location as all the answers I found. Is this the correct folder?

[image]

**The below portion has been solved by the input from @wiimm. However, the added path to the zshrc folder still does not allow me to run the `mysql_config_editor` command, same zsh error.**

After finding this folder I run `nano ~/.zshrc` command and added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/var/mysql/bin` to the file.

[image]

However, when I run the `source ~/.zshrc` command I get a `` /Users/olesn/.zshrc:7: parse error near `\n' `` error.

Are the steps that I am doing correct in order for me to be able to set up the local config file, and if yes, how can I resolve this parse error?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Missing a closing `fi` (not sure about zsh)

Comment: omg, I deleted it as I thought it was some sort of error from a previous time I was tinkering with the file. Thank you, this fixed the zshrc file.

I just run the ```mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=admin --password``` command though, and I still get the ```zsh: command not found: mysql_config_editor``` error.

Comment: There should be a symlink to `mysql_config_editor` in `/usr/local/bin/` (at least that's where brew puts it for mysql, and I'd be surprised if MariaDB was different. It sounds like the dp applications weren't properly linked durning brew's install. Try `brew doctor` to see if you get any clues, and `brew link MariaDB` (or whatever the thing is called) to see if that will set up the links properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB doesn't install `mysql_config_editor` which is why its not found.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. Spent two days chasing a ghost :)

Comment: It did look like a bit of a painful path. Resetting the thought process to a simple solution is hard to see sometimes. Happy MariaDBing, even without `mysql_config_editor`.

Comment: yes, it's something I definitely need to work on.